# Can we delete clauses from linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, expression, linq-expressions, expressionvisitor

I was wondering whether it's possible to add/remove a where clause from a linq expression/ query operators.

Eg :-

```
var qry = from e in emp where(e => e.salary > 5000) select e;
```

Is it possible to remove where expression at a later stage?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible.

Comment: do you mean just: `from e in emp select e`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to implement an `ExpressionVisitor` class to evaluate the composite expression and change it according to your needs.  Unless you are doing something relatively complex there is probably a better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yours is the only answer that really seems to understand, and try to answer, the question.  +1

Answer (score 0):

you can only adjust your filtering as far as i know

for example if are trying to delete  based on condition e.salary > 5000 , they you should try something like

```
var diffQry = from e in emp where(e => e.salary <= 5000) select e;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `WHERE` clause is required if there is a conditional query. Otherwise (if no condition) you can use:

```
var qry = from e in emp select e;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically add and remove where clauses you can use query operators.

```
var query = emp.Select(x => x);

if (someCondition)
  query = query.Where(x => x.Price > 50);
```

You need to expand on your question a little more.

Comment: @Psycho :- I want to delete where after it has been added.

Answer (score 0):

If `qry` is an [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) -- for example, a LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities query -- then it should be possible to analyse the underlying expression tree and build a new one excluding the `Where` clause.

If `qry` is a plain [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) -- for example, a LINQ-to-Objects query -- then this can't be done since there will be no expression tree to analyse.

Comment: - Say if it is IQuerable<T>, can you give me some snippet of how to remove the clause?

Comment: @Kar Cheng: It's not really the sort of thing that can be demonstrated with a small snippet. You'll need some serious code to do this properly, probably using an `ExpressionVisitor`, as @smartcaveman suggests.